# Unable to play or edit .m4a files on fresh Lubuntu 15.10 installation

Tags: sound, lubuntu, codecs, audacity, m4a

I have some m4a files I would like to edit with Audacity, but Audacity crashes when I try to open the files.  In attempting to solve the problem, I found that I'm not able to play m4a files either.  I've tried VLC, Audacious and GNOME MPlayer.

Following various bits of advice from around the internet, I've made sure that I have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed, as well as `lubuntu-restricted-extras` for good measure since I'm on Lubuntu.  `ffmpeg` is also installed.  I installed `libav` from source as well.  Still no joy.

Finally I've made sure that `gstreamer1.0-plugins-good`, `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`, `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly` are installed.  I also installed the 0.10 version because apparently some music players use that version instead of 1.0.

After all this I'm still no closer to playing and editing .m4a files.  The log file after Audacity crashes looks like this:

```
16:35:38: Audacity 2.1.2

16:35:38: Retrieving FFmpeg library version numbers:

16:35:38:    AVCodec version 0x382964 - 56.41.100 (built against 0x382964 - 56.41.100)

16:35:38:    AVFormat version 0x382464 - 56.36.100 (built against 0x382464 - 56.36.100)

16:35:38:    AVUtil version 0x361b64 - 54.27.100 (built against 0x361b64 - 54.27.100)

16:35:45: File name is /home/devon/Desktop/20160131_001.m4a

16:35:45: Mime type is *

16:35:45: Opening with libav
```

This seems to indicate a problem with libav.  I've tried to follow [these instructions](http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=FAQ:Installation_and_Plug-Ins#GNU.2FLinux) to fix the problem, but the "Libraries Preferences" option that I'm directed to doesn't exist in my Audacity install (v.2.1.2).  According to that webpage, that should mean that the library I'm trying to install should already be included in the system, but that doesn't seem to be the case since it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and it had nothing to do with codecs.  The files I copied were corrupted.  They both contained over 40 min of audio but their file sizes were around 130 bytes.  Copying them from the source again solved the problem.